# Merge pandas dataFrames based on row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two .tsv files that look like:

```
ID prop name size
A   x   rob    2
B   y   sally  3
C   z   debby  5
D   w    meg   6
```

and

```
ID lst_name area
A   sanches  4
D    smith   7 
C    roberts  8
```

I have them loaded into pandas DataFrames and would like to merge them so I get a new dataFrame:

```
ID-name prop name size lst_name area
A   x   rob    2    sanches  4
B   y   sally  3
C   z   debby  5   roberts   8
D   w    meg   6    smith    7
```

I have been trying to accomplish this with `pd.merge()` but am having issues with the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("a.tsv", sep='\t')
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("b.tsv", sep='\t')
result = pd.merge(df, df1, how='inner',on=["ID","ID-name"])
```

Is it possible to accomplish a merge like this with pandas?

Answer (score 0):

What you would need is an left join (or outer join, of course depending on your case), since in this sample you also would like to see the records for B even though it has no records on df1.

`result = pd.merge(df, df1, how="left",on=["ID","ID"])`

```
      prop   name  size lst_name  area
ID ID
A  A     x    rob     2  sanches   4.0
B  B     y  sally     3      NaN   NaN
C  C     z  debby     5  roberts   8.0
D  D     w    meg     6    smith   7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','B','C','D'],'prop':['x','y','z','w'],'name':['rob','sally','debby','meg'],'size':[2,3,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','D','C'],'lst_name':['sanches','smith','roberts'],'area':[4,7,8]})
df1.set_index('ID').join(df2.set_index('ID')).reset_index()

>>>
  ID prop   name  size lst_name  area
0  A    x    rob     2  sanches   4.0
1  B    y  sally     3      NaN   NaN
2  C    z  debby     5  roberts   8.0
3  D    w    meg     6    smith   7.0
```